# How to complete an html line with a symbol _

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, dompdf

**What I need:**
dynamictextdynamictextdynamictextdynamictextdynamictextdynamictextdynamictext_________________________(... until the endline)

---

---

**I have:**

```
<div style="???">
   {{dynamictext}}
</div>
<hr />
<hr />
```

I'm using html to generate a report with Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF. I have a dynamic text into a div and when this text ends I need the entire rest of the last line be filled with _. Or maybe a way else to fullfill the line with a dash.

This is because in this report a people will handwrite something. I put hr's with other lines, but I need to fill the rest of the last line as well.

Comment: Can we see an example/template of an entire report in HTML?  Depending how it's laid out you may be able to throw a <span> to fill the rest of the line.

Comment: <pre><html lang="pt-BR">
<style>
hr {
width: 100%;
height: 1px;
background-color: #000;
border: none;
}
.secao {
width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
<div>

<div class="secao">
Eu, MMMM MMMM MMMMM MMM aluno(a) regularmente
matriculado(a) e frequente no 3 período, no ano letivo de..., ministrada pelo Prof.(a) RRRRRRR RRRRR RRRRRRR, e
realizada no dia ___/___/______, por motivo de
<br>
<hr>
<hr>
</div>
<div class="secao">
(Anexar documento comprobatório, se houver)
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
</pre>

Answer (score 1):

In HTML there's basically no way to know how may characters will fit in a line. Since you're using HTML merely as proxy to generate PDFs, I'd look for some silly trick like:

```css
.dynamic {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
.signature {
  width: 99%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="dynamic">Dynamic Text Here</td>
    <td class="signature"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.dynamic{
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
.signature {
  width: 99%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dynamic">Dynamic Text Here</div>
  <div class="signature"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.dynamic{
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
.signature {
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dynamic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit mundi moderatius in, in similique consectetuer per, his te persius consetetur. Ad ius qualisque posidonium neglegentur, et iudico tamquam legimus cum. At alii iisque docendi ius. Ne oblique menandri complectitur eum, his cu omnis mentitum invidunt.</div>
  <div class="signature"></div>
</div>
```

(Which one to use depends on the CSS capabilities of [your HTML renderer](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf).)

Comment: That's a good trick. I was thinking about using a pseudo-class with lines behind text with a white text-shadow (to hide the lines) but that seemed overly complex and unlikely to work in the HTML->PDF conversion.

Comment: Thank you for that. It's a good try, but in may case I have many lines, so the nowrap forces only one line and my content overflows the page. Without nowrap the content break lines on every whitespace.

Comment: I only used the `white-space` property to prevent my sample text from displaying in several lines. The key point is using boxes of some kind instead of typing underscores. Boxes can be resized to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

The difficult thing here is to know the length you need for the line, but in your controller, you could do something like this:

```
$text = 'Hello';
$text = str_pad($text, 100, '_');
```

that would give you a line with 100 characters with _ at the end.

Comment: you miss `'` after `'_`

Comment: this does not work because the length depends of width and it can have many lines